# MongoDB - 2 redundant Databases - loadbalancing + failover

Tags: mongodb

I am running two Webservers on Ubuntu Version 20.04 and on each one I have a Docker Container where my data is stored.

I am trying to implement redundancy because the Servers need to be on "the same page" due to Loadbalancing.

Is there a way to mirror those databases?

[image: Topology]